# How to replace Deno.env calls when bundling

Tags: deno

I'm attempting to build a script to be run in the browser and I wish to replace `Deno.env.get(...)` calls with the actual value I'm passing.

Does Deno have a built in way to handle this?

My expectation was something like:

```js
// mod.ts
console.log(Deno.env.get('MY_VAR'));
```

```bash
# in terminal
MY_VAR=hello deno bundle --allow-env mod.ts bundle.js
```

```js
// bundle.js
console.log("hello") // this doesn't happen.. still Deno.env.get('MY_VAR')
```

Answer (score -1):

Deno has no built-in way to replace `Deno.env.get(...)` when bunding.

So I wrote my own build script that *only* handles strings.

```js
// build.ts
interface BuildParams {
  input: string;
  output: string;
  env: Record<string, string>;
}

const build = async ({ input, output, env }: BuildParams) => {
  const process = Deno.run({
    cmd: [
      "deno",
      "bundle",
      input,
      output,
    ],
  });
  await process.status();

  const bundle = await Deno.readTextFile(output);

  const parsedBundle = Object.entries(env).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => {
      const searchString = `Deno\\.env\\.get\\("${key}"\\)`;
      const regExp = new RegExp(searchString, "g");
      acc = acc.replace(regExp, `"${value}"`);
      return acc;
    },
    bundle,
  );

  await Deno.writeTextFile(output, parsedBundle);
};

export default build;
```

And an example usage:

```js
await build({
  input: Deno.cwd() + "/lib/mod.ts",
  output: Deno.cwd() + "/public/javascript/build/upc-bundle.js",
  env: {
    SERVER_URL: Deno.env.get("SERVER_URL") ?? "ws://127.0.0.1:3012",
  }
});
```